# "R studio Not opening"

Tags: r, installation

I installed R studio 1.2.1335 in my Pc powered by Win 7 x64.
after installation when i try to open R studio shows error "**api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll is missing**" 
how to fix this error?

I tried to reinstall R studio, but problem continuous

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try installing

Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015 found in this link

https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=48145

it will fix your error